# Term for Adding Functionality to Type at Runtime

Tags: types

Sometimes in my programs I've added a function to a type after it has been produced or rebound an type's existing function.
I've called this "monkey wrenching."

Is there an accepted term for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more common term is ["monkey patching"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch), although Wikipedia claims "duck punching" is sometimes used as well.

Comment: surprised i somehow got so close to the correct name!  i must have read it at some point.  thank you!